# Non-Recursive Merge Sort in Java

Tags: java, arrays, mergesort

I am working on a non recursive merge sort for my CS class and it is not exactly working. I know it is being called since when I run the test program it changes the array, just not into the correct order. Can someone please help? Thanks!

```
private static void mergeSort(int[] a, int left, int right)
{
    int midPoint = ((right + left) / 2);
    int[] buffer = new int[19];

    selectionSort(a, left, midPoint);
    selectionSort(a, midPoint-1, right);
    merge(a, buffer, 0, 9, 19);
}

private static void selectionSort(int[] a, int beginning, int end)
{
    int [] temp = new int[end-1];

    for(int y = 0; y < end - 1; y++)
    {
        temp[y] = a[y]; 
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < temp.length - 1; i++)
    {
        int minIndex = findMinimum(temp, i);
        if (minIndex != i)
            swap (temp, i, minIndex);
    }
}

private static int findMinimum(int[] a, int first)
{
    int minIndex = first;

    for (int i = first + 1; i < a.length; i++)
    {
        if (a[i] < a[minIndex])
            minIndex = i;
    }
    return minIndex;
}

private static void swap(int []a, int x, int y)
{
    int temp = a[x];
    a[x] = a[y];
    a[y] = temp;
}

private static void merge(int[] a, int[] temp, int left, int mid, int right) {
    if (mid >= a.length) return;
    if (right > a.length) right = a.length;
    int i = left, j = mid+1;
    for (int k = left; k < right; k++) {
       if      (i == mid)     
           temp[k] = a[j++];
       else if (j == right)      
           temp[k] = a[i++];
       else if (a[j] < a[i])  
           temp[k] = a[j++];
       else                   
           temp[k] = a[i++];
    }
    for (int k = left; k < right; k++)
       a[k] = temp[k];
 }
```

Comment: Why do you use your parameters `left` and `right`, and the midpoint `midPoint`, when calling `selectionSort`--but then use hard-wired constants when calling `merge`?  And why do you hard-wire the length of `buffer`--why not `int[] buffer = new int[a.length]`?

Comment: I hand-wired them into to make sure the parameters had the correct values which they did and forgot to put them back as the paarameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be other bugs, but one that sticks out is that `selectionSort` doesn't actually do anything to the array.  You pass in an array reference as the `a` parameter:

```
private static void selectionSort(int[] a, int beginning, int end)
```

Since this is a reference, if `selectionSort` did anything to assign to any elements of `a`, like

```
a[x] = y;
```

it would change the element of the caller's array, like you want.  But there is no statement in `selectionSort` that changes anything in `a`.  The code copies elements to `temp`, works with `temp`--but then throws all the work away.

Comment: Thanks! I realized that the whole temp thing in the selectonSort was unnecessary. I just got rid of it and started it at the second for loop and changed all of the temp to a and it worked! Thanks a bunch!